# I run into an error when attempting to add today's date to file name

Tags: date, filenames

I suspect the error is where I attempted to add today's date to the filename.

```
ChDir _
    "C:\Users\xxx\PRODUCT MGT Position Tracking\Stock reports"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\xxx\PRODUCT MGT Position Tracking\Stock reports\Stock by product by location " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd").csv _
    , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: Insufficient context (OS, language, tools) for question to be answered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.